# Почему getline насчитывает 40 строк?

Tags: строки, c++

```
string fileName(filepath);
ifstream inData;
inData.open(fileName.c_str());
if (!inData)
    return 0;
int size = 0;
while (inData.good()) {
    inData.getline(temp, 4096, ',');
    size++;
}
```

`size == 40`, хотя строк файле всего 18. Как?

Comment: код супер и вопрос супер

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так у Вас же ограничитель `','` - запятая. Вот вы и считываете и считаете куски, расположенные между запятыми.

Comment: да уже въехал, че то затупил я.

Comment: спс все равно